# remote debug scala.html view in play2

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Is there any option to debug scala.html view file in play2. Should it be defined in different format? 
Can debug controllers which is written in Java.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Intellij idea. remote debug